# Pandas group by, filter & plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, group-by, filtering

I have a dataframe

```
Date         rule_name
Jan 1 2016   A
Feb 4 2016   B
Jun 6 2016   C
Feb 5 2016   B
Feb 9 2016   D
Jun 5 2016   A
```

And so on ...

I am hoping to get a dataframe for each rule similar to below:
E.g. Dataframe for rule_name A:

```
date       counts (rule_name)   %_rule_name 
Jan 16     1                   100
Feb 16     0                    0
Jun 16     1                   50
```

E.g Dataframe for rule_name B:

```
date        counts (rule_name)   %_rule_name 
Jan 16      0                   0
Feb 16      2                   66.6
Jun 16      0                   0
```

Etc.

My current solution:

```
rule_names = df['rule_name'].unique().tolist()
for i in rule_names:
    df_temp = df[df['rule_name'] == i]
    df_temp = df.groupby(df['date'].map(lambda x: str(x.year) + '-' + str(x.strftime('%m')))).count()
    df_temp.plot(kind='line', title = 'Rule Name: ' + str(i))
```

As you can see I am unable to get the % of rule name and am only plotting the count_rule_name.  I feel like there is (a) a solution and (b) a better solution then iterating through the each rule name and plotting but am unable to figure it out unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

***Solution***
Use `df.Date.str.split().str[0]` to get months

```
df.groupby([df.Date.str.split().str[0]]).rule_name.value_counts(True) \
  .unstack(fill_value=0).mul(100).round(1)
```

[image]

***Plot***

```
df.groupby([df.Date.str.split().str[0]]).rule_name.value_counts(True) \
  .unstack(fill_value=0).mul(100).round(1).plot.bar()
```

[image]

***Validate Counts***

```
df.groupby([df.Date.str.split().str[0], df.rule_name]).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful - but I am trying to bring it into the same dataframe so I can plot them on the same plot.   I.e. Rule name for the plot, each month a count and then on the right y axis would be a % plot .... do you think that is possible?

Comment: @SteelyDanish I was completely guessing at what you wanted.  If this isn't it, you'll have to put more effort into showing us what you expect.

Comment: thanks for commentary - updated for clarity  @piRSquared

Comment: To further what you did - I am hoping to combine the first table and the second table you created but for each rule_name @piRSquared

Comment: I took your comments to heart and re-explained the question in a better format --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597785/pandas-multicolumn-groupby-plotting  I will close this one off.